# How can I play audio (playsound) in the background of a Python script?

Tags: python, audio, python-playsound

I am just writing a small Python game for fun and I have a function that does the beginning narrative.

I am trying to get the audio to play in the background, but unfortunately the MP3 file plays first before the function continues.

How do I get it to run in the background?

```
import playsound

def displayIntro():
    playsound.playsound('storm.mp3',True)
    print('')
    print('')
    print_slow('The year is 1845, you have just arrived home...')
```

Also, is there a way of controlling the volume of the *playsound* module?

I am using a Mac, and I am not wedded to using playsound. It just seems to be the only module that I can get working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Windows:

Use *winsound.SND_ASYNC* to play them asynchronously:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound("filename", winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_ALIAS )
```

To stop playing

```
winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

On Mac or other platforms:

You can try this [Pygame/SDL](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.io/en/rel_0_9_5/)

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("file.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. I managed to get the pygame sound to work, thank you. However it is not playing in the background. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I had left a playsound code in the script. The pygame mixer isn't playing any sound :/

Comment: Fixed it, it just wouldn't play .mp3 files. It works with .wav files

Comment: Yes try to convert mp3 to wav using `pymedia` i guess

Answer (score 22):

Just change `True` to `False` (I use Python 3.7.1)

```
import playsound
playsound.playsound('storm.mp3', False)
print ('...')
```

Comment: Info: This does not work using Ubuntu 20.04. It gives the following error: ``NotImplementedError: block=False cannot be used on this platform yet``

Comment: This worked for me on Windows with Python 3.7.3

Comment: after some testing it looks like this only works on windows due to the underlying Gstreamer implementation that is only configured for windows drivers

Comment: This seems to work on Ubuntu 20.04 too now.

Comment: win10 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playsound'

Comment: so install playsound if you didn't, and if you did it's an error

Answer (score 4):

There is a library *in* [Pygame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame) called *mixer* and you can add an MP3 file to the folder with the Python script inside and put code like this inside:

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("mysong.mp3")
mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: This is the same as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472162/how-can-i-play-audio-playsound-in-the-background-of-a-python-script/44472225#44472225) (but much better explained).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could just use pygame.mixer.music.play(x):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Any problems contact me on Instagram, @vulnerabilties
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('filename.extention')
pygame.mixer.music.play(999)

# Your code here
```

Comment: Is @vulnerabilties on Instagram you? Or somebody else? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

You could try *[just_playback](https://github.com/cheofusi/just_playback)*. It's a wrapper I wrote around *[miniaudio](https://github.com/mackron/miniaudio)* that plays audio in the background while providing playback control functionality like pausing, resuming, seeking and setting the playback volume.

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to do it is to use vlc. Very common and supported library.

```
pip install python-vlc
```

Then writing your code

```
import vlc

#Then instantiate a MediaPlayer object

player = vlc.MediaPlayer("/path/to/song.mp3")

#And then use the play method

player.play()

#You can also use the methods pause() and stop if you need.

player.pause()
player.stop

#And for the super fancy thing you can even use a playlist :)

playlist = ['/path/to/song1.mp3', '/path/to/song2.mp3', '/path/to/song3.mp3']

    for song in playlist:
        player = vlc.MediaPlayer(song)
        player.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.music.init()
mixer.music.load("audio.mp3") # Paste The audio file location 
mixer.play()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The code is practically identical to the code in [Rinzler786's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472162/how-can-i-play-audio-playsound-in-the-background-of-a-python-script/53906487#53906487) (though the code comment is a slight improvement). And that answer has an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I used a separate thread to play the sound without blocking the main thread. It works on Ubuntu as well.

```py
from threading import Thread
from playsound import playsound

def play(path):
    """
    Play sound file in a separate thread
    (don't block current thread)
    """
    def play_thread_function:
        playsound(path)

    play_thread = Thread(target=play_thread_function)
    play_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution to reproduce similar length sounds. This solution worked to me to solve the error:

> The specified device is not open or recognized by MCI.

Here follow the syntax as a class method, but you can change it to work even without a class.

Import these packages:

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time
```

Define this function:

```
def _reproduce_sound_nb(self, str_, time_s):
        def reproduce_and_kill(str_, time_sec=time_s):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=playsound, args=(str_,))
            p.start()
            time.sleep(time_sec)
            p.terminate()
        threading.Thread(target=reproduce_and_kill, args=(str_, time_s), daemon=True).start()
```

In the main program/method:

```
self._reproduce_sound_nb(sound_path, 3) # path to the sound, seconds after sound stop -> to manage the process end
```

Comment: why have you used both multiprocessing and threading at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Use [vlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings)

```
import vlc
player = None
def play(sound_file):
    global player
    if player is not None:
        player.stop()
    player = vlc.MediaPlayer("file://" + sound_file)
    player.play()
```

Comment: Can you [expand this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67877810/edit)? E.g., what is required to be installed? [VLC media player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player)? Or something else (some development files not part of the VLC media player installation)? Or completely independent of VLC media player itself (some stand-alone libraries)? What platform did you test this on? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: [rambopython's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472162/how-can-i-play-audio-playsound-in-the-background-of-a-python-script/68877343#68877343) is less terse.