# How to play a sound in python (Windows)

Tags: python, windows

I was making a game in python and wanted to add sound, so I did so. Wondering if there's a way to play the sound but not pause the rest of my code? (was using winsound)

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use can use winsound.SND_ASYNC to play without stopping the code.
To play:
    `import winsound`
    `winsound.PlaySound("filename", winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_ALIAS )`
To stop:
    `winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_ASYNC)`
[Original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472162/how-do-play-audio-playsound-in-background-of-python-script)