# How can I play music in background in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, audio, pygame, background-music

I'm doing something like a vocal assistant in python. Through different modules, I managed to download a youtube video and convert it to mp3. Now I'd like to play it and being capable of pausing it and other actions. I tried with pygame but I couldn't use it without opening a window. Any suggestion?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44472225/11266757) answers a similar question and may be of help

Answer (score 1):

There are good libraries for this. Check [here](https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/).
Also you can use terminal commands for example :

```
import os
os.system('xdg-open music.mp3')
# music is playing ...
```

I use **MOC** player in cli that can play and pause music on background for example :

```
import os 
os.system('moc -l music.mp3')    #play music 
os.system('moc -P music.mp3')    #pause music
os.system('moc -U music.mp3')    #unpause music
```

Comment: Yeah but no one of these can pause it for example.

Comment: something for windows?

Comment: @Filippo I don't know about windows , I use this on linux .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the playsound module in python after installing it with pip like so

```py
from playsound import playsound

playsound('path\to\your\music\file.mp3', False)
```

- the False argument lets the sound play in the background
- sadly this can only work on windows as it is implemented for windows drivers till now

Answer (score 0):

By using VLC

first of all, install vlc

```
$ pip install python-vlc
```

then you can add this to your code

```
import vlc

player = vlc.MediaPlayer("/path/to/song.mp3")

player.play()
```

and just like this, you can play music in the background.
you can even control it!

```
# to pause music
player.pause()

# to stop music
player.stop()
```

You can make a function like this one

```
import vlc

player = None

def play_music(path):
    global player
    if player is not None:
        player.stop # this code stop old music (if exist) before starting new one

    player = vlc.MediaPlayer(path)
    player.play()
```