# How do I play music and use speak command work at the same time?

Tags: python, python-playsound

I am trying to create a voice assistant program using Python and want my program to play music in the background and **wishme** at the same time. But when I'm trying to do so, the program first executes the  `playsound.playsound()` and then executes the **wishme** command. What should I do?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    playsound.playsound('C:\\Users\\socia\\Downloads\\jack_sparrow_bgm.mp3')
    wishMe()
    while True:

      query = takeCommand().lower()

      if 'wikipedia' in query:
          speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
          query = query.replace("wikipedia", "").replace("on", "").replace("search", "")
          results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
          speak('Here is your result SIR.')
          print(results)
          speak(results)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with threads?

Comment: no :( .........

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play audio (playsound) in the background of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472162/how-to-play-audio-playsound-in-the-background-of-a-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

Use the threading module. This will make your tasks independent of each other.
Example,

```
import threading

def task_1():
    #do something like play music

def task_2():
    #do something like search wiki

#Run the code
threading.Thread(target=task_1).start()
threading.Thread(target=task_2).start()
```

Read more on the threading module for customising it as per your need

Comment: Probably don't want to create the threads and start them in an infinite loop like that…

Comment: Edited to remove the loop, which doesn't make any sense. It's possible, but certainly not guaranteed that the *worker functions* might want to loop infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

**Use :**
`os.startfile('C:\\Users\\socia\\Downloads\\jack_sparrow_bgm.mp3')`.

It is more advance and I am also making the same program for myself currently and using OS module and faced no problem.

Comment: but this OS module redirects me to the default music player to play the music... And I want the program to play music in the background as well as speak the commands for some specific period of time (while starting)...