# tkinter audio button plays sound as many times as it was clicked

Tags: python, tkinter, playsound

i have a tkinter button setup for my program. it plays a sound file. however, if i press the button while the audio is playing, the sound file will be queued and play again once its over. i want the button to be unresponsive (so it doesnt queue the audio) while its playing. this is my code:

```
soundInstructions = 0
def setSoundInstructions(filename):
    global soundInstructions
    soundInstructions = os.path.join(filename)

def playInstructions():
    playsound(soundInstructions)

soundButton = tkinter.Button(frame, image = soundImage, command = lambda: playInstructions(), borderwidth = 0, height= 25, width = 25)
soundButton.pack(side = TOP)
```

Comment: You should probably look into an alternative audio library then.  playsound doesn't provide any features such as checking the duration or time remaining on a track or create and signals or flags for when the audio track has finished.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the `playsound` library. When you click on the button and run the function, `playsound` will freeze the whole code until the sound is finished. To fix this, simply add a `False` after the file path.

```py
def playInstructions():
    playsound(soundInstructions, False)
```

You can visit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54074889/17990633) for more information.

---

The reason why it works is because the `playsound()` function of the `playsound` library has 2 arguments, one is the file path that you put in, and the other one which you can set it to block the code or not.

In *`playsound.py`*:

```py
def _playsoundWin(sound, block = True):
    [...]
```

If you set the `block` argument to `False`, it won't block the code.

---

**The full code:**

```py
soundInstructions = 0
def setSoundInstructions(filename):
    global soundInstructions
    soundInstructions = os.path.join(filename)

def playInstructions():
    playsound(soundInstructions, False)

soundButton = tkinter.Button(frame, image = soundImage, command = lambda: playInstructions(), borderwidth = 0, height= 25, width = 25)
soundButton.pack(side = TOP)
```

**NOTE:** I don't recommend you to use the `playsound` library to play sounds in Python. Instead of that, you should use some other better alternatives such as [`winsound`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html) (Windows) or [`pygame.mixer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html).