# Program freezing in python customtkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pytube, customtkinter

i'm trying to learn tkinter/customtkinter so i followed a guide that made a youtube video downloader with customtkinter [GUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NI9LXzo0UY0) but when i download a video the program freezes for like 10mins then it actually downloads

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from pytube import YouTube


def startdownload():
    try:
        ytLink = link.get()
        ytObject = YouTube(ytLink, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
        video = ytObject.streams.get_lowest_resolution()
        
        title.configure(text=ytObject.title)

        video.download()
        finishlabel.configure(text="Downloaded")
    except:
        finishlabel.configure(text="Invlaid")


def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaning):
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaning
    percentage_of_compeletion = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
    per = str(int(percentage_of_compeletion))
    number.configure(text=per + "%")
    number.update()

    bar.set(float(percentage_of_compeletion) / 100)


    


customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("720x480")
app.title("Youtube Downloader")

title = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="Enter Video Link")
title.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

url_var = tkinter.StringVar()
link = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, width=350, height=40, textvariable=url_var)
link.pack()

finishlabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="")
finishlabel.pack()

number = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="0%")
number.pack()

bar = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(app, width=400)
bar.set(0)
bar.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

download = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, width=200, text="Download", command=startdownload)
download.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

#app run loop
app.mainloop()
```

tried asking chatgpt but that didnt help

Comment: This kind of problem is usually caused by doing something synchronously on the main thread. "Synchronously" means every event happens in the sequence your program specifies, one after another. That means if one step (for example, downloading the video) takes a long time, nothing else (including interacting with other GUI elements) will be able to happen until that step is done. The fix is to make the time-consuming step *asynchronous*. "Asynchronous" means the long task is constantly being "swapped out" with other events (such as checking for user interaction) until it completes.

Comment: For example, playing a sound file (with `playsound`) can be done either synchronously or asynchronously, depending on whether the `blocking` argument is set to `true` or `false` (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54074889/18248018). I would suggest doing a search for a way to download videos asynchronously, and see what comes up.

Comment: Another approach would be to have the download happen synchronously on a *background thread* - I don't know whether the tutorial you're following discusses multithreading

Comment: @QuackE.Duck no the video doesn't discuss multithreating, and if what you're saying about not being able to interact with the GUI until video is downloaded is true then the program should freeze for only a couple of seconds because the video i'm trying to download is only 2mbs

Comment: Then I have no idea what's causing the problem, so +1 for an interesting question!